# Create image gallery programmatically

Tags: product-images

I need generate image gallery programmatically. I have near 1M products and product images import is too slowly.

I created controller, which return image if it exists and generate images if it not exists.

I'm successfully override getImageUrl() in \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Image and view my images in product list (such as a search result).

But I need show custom images in product view too. I'm trying override getMediaGalleryImages in Product.php, but don't know how.

```
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Model;
class Product extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
{

     //constructors here

    public function getMediaGalleryImages()
    {
        $images = $this->_collectionFactory->create();
        $image['url'] = "/mycontroller/image/generate/sku_here";
        $images->addItem($image);

        return $images;
    }
```

Any ideas?